# Remove section numbering from fancyhdr header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, fancyhdr

I have a document containing my course notes, and am attempting to alter the fancyhdr header as in the images below:

## Current

[image: current]

## Wanted

[image: wanted]

Here is my current header code, with irrelevant parts omitted.

```
\documentclass[english, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\chead{\coursename}
\lhead{\semester}

\begin{document}

\section{Lecture 1}
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

What I would like is for the right header to contain the section name (and only the section name) **of the current page**, the actual section titles in the document to contain only the section name, but the table of contents to retain the section number. Please note I have only limited TeX experience (self-taught), so this is a fairly steep learning curve for me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you omit `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` in your MWE. Please edit your question so that it corresponds to Minimal Working Example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly alternative suggestion based on the fact that you're probably going to enumerate all lectures one after the other, and not really "name" them. Therefore, instead of using

```
\section{Lecture 1}
```

use some automated

```
\newlecture
```

which will print the heading, do some formatting, and adjust the header/footer accordingly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chead{\coursename}
\lhead{\semester}
\rhead{\lecturename{} \thelecture}

\newcommand{\coursename}{Engineering Numerical Methods}
\newcommand{\semester}{Semester 1 2015}
\newcommand{\lecturename}{Lecture}

\newcounter{lecture}
\newcommand{\newlecture}{%
  \clearpage
  \refstepcounter{lecture}%
  \noindent{\large\bfseries \lecturename{} \thelecture}%
  \par\bigskip\noindent\ignorespaces%
}

\begin{document}

\newlecture\label{lec:first}%
\lipsum[1-3]

\newlecture
In Lecture~\ref{lec:first}, we examined \ldots
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```